How to determine optimal grouping?
Problem: Given elements and sets that the elements can corespond to, find optimal division these elements to sets, such that number of sets is minimal.
Example:
'a' : (1, 2),
'b' : (1, 3),
'c' : (3, 5),
'd' : (2, 6)

This input means that a can be only in set 1 or set 2, b can be only in set 1 or set 3 and so on.
This example should give an answer of 2 with sets: set number 2 and set number 3. As we can put a and d into set 2 and b and c into set 3. That is the optimal partitioning.
Is this well known problem? Or maybe NP-hard problem? Anybody know how to approach or solve it?

It isn't quite clear when elements can, cannot, or must belong to the same set, but if my guess is correct, this is just the minimal set cover problem.

Ok I will clarify that in the problem statement

Is the problem description clear now?

Sounds like the set cover problem.
